# Compare two array's and disable a single element if the id's are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two array in the state and both have id's.

if some array have the same value (In this case 8) I would like to disable all the buttons that have this equal value.

The buttons already exist, I just want to disable the ones that have the same non-unique ids.

I tried like this but i'm not getting it

```
var setOne = [2,6,8];
var setTwo = [3, 8, 4]

const button = () => {
var hasDuplicateValues = [...new Set(setOne)].filter(item => setTwo.includes(item));

if(hasDuplicateValues.length > 0) {
   <button disabled />
}
else {
    <button />
}
}
```

```
render(){
this.button()
}
```

This solution is disabling all the buttons but i want to disable the one with the same id only.

Thanks

Comment: `hasDuplicateValues` only has 8 in it, so _why_ it's disabling all of the buttons is in the code you haven't added.

Comment: No issues in the code you posted so far - it would be good if you could show the code for your buttons - so we know how to target a button that has a duplicate ID.

Comment: Please post [minimal, complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I edited the component

Comment: Pre-existing buttons? new buttons? pretty unclear in the problem description here.

Comment: The button already exist, i just want to disable the ones that have the same id's

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear where in the app hierarchy that component is so I've attempted a bit of guess work. You're almost there by the looks of things. You just need to iterate over the buttons and create them.

```js
function Button(props) {
  const { disabled, text } = props;
  return <button disabled={disabled}>{text}</button>;
}

// Buttons creates the buttons in the set
function Buttons() {

  const setOne = [2, 6, 8];
  const setTwo = [3, 8, 4];

  // Remove the duplicates from the combined sets
  const combined = [...new Set([...setOne, ...setTwo])];

  // Get your duplicate values
  const hasDuplicateValues = setOne.filter(item => setTwo.includes(item));
  
  // `map` over the combined buttons
  // If `hasDuplicateValues` includes the current button, disable it
  return combined.map((n) => (
    <Button
      text={n}
      disabled={hasDuplicateValues.includes(n) && 'disabled'}
    />
  ));

}

ReactDOM.render(<Buttons />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Looks like a good guess set but what about if the buttons already exist? (which I infer from the poorly created question - so I voted appropriately on that)