# Check if two array are equal and disable a button of array that have same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'am rendering cards and i have two array, i would like to disable the buttons that have an equal id between the two array.

for expemple:

```
idOne = [9,5,1,4];
idTwo = [6,1,3,4];
```

In this case i would like to disable the button for 4 and 1 since both have the same value.

here is the render method where i pass the button

```
render(){
this.button()
}
```

Here is my try

```
button = () {
idOne = [9,5,1,4];
idTwo = [6,1,3,4];

const checkId = idOne.some(n => idTwo.includes(n))
if(checkedId){
return <Button disable />
} 

return <Button />
}
}
```

But this will disable all the buttons and not the ones that have equal id's.

thanks for the help

Comment: How do the ids relate to the buttons?

Comment: I pass a function and on click to the button it add the id

Comment: How are you removing the ids that you already tested? This code here: `const checkId = idOne.some(n => idTwo.includes(n))` will run over and over again with the exact same values, giving you the same result every time.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541212/compare-two-arrays-and-disable-a-single-element-if-the-ids-are-equal/58541550 from an hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

I broke it down into two seperate steps. First I would use filter to return an array of all the ids that match between the two ids.

```
const arr1 = [9, 5, 1, 4]
const arr2 = [6, 1, 3, 4]
const matches = arr1.filter(el => arr2.includes(el)
```

Then once I have an array of all the matches you can `map` over all the ids in arr1 and then do the check if any ids sync up. This will return a bool value that will allow you to render conditional components

```
return arr1.map(el => {
   if (matches.includes(el)) {
       return <Button disable />
   }

   return <Button />
})
```

You could refactor it down even smaller to 1 step if you wanted by chaining the filter and the map

Comment: Thank you, but it's disabling all the buttons, when i console.log(matches.includes(el)) i got [true];

So if it's true it's disabling all the buttons

Comment: This returns true or false for each item in the array. Not just true or false 1 time

Comment: I've run this and it returns [false, false, true, true]